# How to compare two different Firebase database child items f

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help in order to implement a functionality in my app such that if the user chooses a restaurant, a list of items that are available in the restaurant are displayed and if there are none, it displays a text and a button.

I went about it like this:I would compare two child items, the restaurant names to check if they are equal.If they are, it displays a recyclerview with a list of the items available.

[Here is a screenshot of my firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G05es.png)

My goal is to 
1. compare if the string at donationplceTxt (under the All Donations child) is equal to the string at place (under Food Request Restaurant).

Here's a code snippet of where I get the restaurant name from. Note that it is in another activity called RequestActivity.java. The actual comparison is done when I want to display the items from the database in a recycler view which is inside DisplayItems.java

Code snippet for RequestActivity.java which handles the place

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // check to see if selected place is a restaurant
            boolean isARestaurant = false;
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            for (int i : place.getPlaceTypes()) {
                if (    i == Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT ||
                        i == Place.TYPE_CAFE
                        ) {
                    isARestaurant = true;
                    StringBuilder stBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String placename = String.format("%s", place.getName());
                    // String latitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude);
                    // String longitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude);
                    String address = String.format("%s", place.getAddress());
                    stBuilder.append(placename);
                    stBuilder.append(", ");
                    stBuilder.append(address);
                    placeTxt.setText(stBuilder.toString());
                    mkRqstBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    requestPlceTxt = placeTxt.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("First instance of Request place here : " + requestPlceTxt);
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    userID = user.getUid();

                    // String id =  UserReqPlaceRef.push().getKey();
                    Request request = new Request(requestPlceTxt);
                    // save to database
                    UserReqPlaceRef.child("Food Request Restaurant")
                            .child(userID)
                            .push()
                            .setValue(request);

                    // use intent extra to send data to display items activity
                    // Intent myintent=new Intent(RequestActivity.this, DisplayItems.class).putExtra("sentPlace", requestPlceTxt);
                    // startActivity(myintent);

                    break;
                }
                if(isARestaurant){
                    //Right type of place
                }else{
                    //Tell to the user to select an appropriate place = restaurant
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a Restaurant",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code snippet from DisplayActivity.java where I'm supposed to display the items available (if there are any) at that particular restuarant

```
// get key id for each instance of donation
    final String donateId =   rootRef.child("All Donations").child(curtUserId).getKey();
    // get key each instance of request
    final String requestId =   rootRef.child("Food Request Restaurant").child(curtUserId).getKey();

    // make a query for all first 50 donation items in All Donations reference
    final Query latestQuery = rootRef
            .child("All Donations")
            .child(curtUserId)
            .orderByKey()
            .limitToFirst(50);

    final DatabaseReference reqRestLoc = rootRef   
            .child("Food Request Restaurant")
            .child(curtUserId)
            .child(requestId);

    // code here to retrieve the string value located at reqRestLoc
    // then compare it with donateRest
    // make another value event listener and get the string?



    latestQuery.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    donationList.clear();

                    for (DataSnapshot gigSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Donation donation = gigSnapshot
                                .getValue(Donation.class);


                        donationList.add(donation);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        String donateRest = (String) dataSnapshot
                                .child("All Donations")
                                .child(donateId)
                                .getValue();

                       /* if (s.equals(donateRest)) {   // s = string from reqRestLoc. Does not work
                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            noItemsTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            OkExitBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            OkExitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    DisplayItems.super.onBackPressed();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            noItemsTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            OkExitBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }*/
                    }
                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

}
```

Thanks a lot!